# JPQL LIKE expression on enum

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

Can JPQL execute LIKE expressions against enums?

If I have an entity Foo with an enum field bar I can execute the following in MySQL(bar is stored as a MySQL enum)...

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE `bar` LIKE '%SUFFIX'
```

However, the corresponding query in JPQL...

```
SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.bar LIKE '%SUFFIX'
```

...complains that...

```
Parameter value [%SUFFIX] was not matching type [com.example.Foo$EnumType]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I  don't think it's possible, the left part of a `LIKE` is supposed to be a *string_expression* (in standard JPA). From the specification:

> #### 4.6.9 Like Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator [NOT] LIKE in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> string_expression [NOT] LIKE pattern_value [ESCAPE escape_character]
> ```
>
> The *string_expression* must have a
>   string value. The *pattern_value* is
>   a string literal or a string-valued
>   input parameter in which an underscore
>   (_) stands for any single character,
>   a percent (%) character stands for any
>   sequence of characters (including the
>   empty sequence), and all other
>   characters stand for themselves. The
>   optional *escape_character* is a
>   single-character string literal or a
>   character-valued input parameter
>   (i.e., `char` or `Character`) and is
>   used to escape the special meaning of
>   the underscore and percent characters
>   in *pattern_value*.

And an *enum_expression* is not a *string_expression*.

The following would work though (using *enum literals*):

```
SELECT f 
  FROM Foo f 
 WHERE f.bar = com.acme.Bar.SOME_CONSTANT 
    OR f.bar = com.acme.Bar.SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT
```

Another option would be to actually store the `bar` field as a `String` (and to do some conversion from and to an enum in the getter/setter).

#### Reference

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.6.9 "Like Expressions"
  - Section 4.14 "BNF"

Answer (score 1):

What JPA provider and version are you using?

This should work in EclipseLink 2.1.

Otherwise you could try applying a function to the enum to change it to a varchar, or use native SQL, or map it as a String instead.

Comment: I'm currently using Hibernate though I'm trying to stick with pure JPA/JPQL.  I ended up checking the type of the field that was being queried (through the JPA 2.0 criteria API).  If the type was assignable from Enum then I casted the users argument to the appropriate enum value.